# Group centroids and draw a rectangle

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using `opencv` to detect many objects in a image.

I can detect all objects and draw its centroids like it:

[image: Detected Centroids]

Now I need to group the nearest centroids and discard alones. Like this:

[image]

How can I retrieve an array of bounding boxes for grouped centroids?

Comment: For each centroid, search all other centroids for any that are within some maximum distance. If found, create a group. Once you have groups, you can find the bounds of the centroids (min and max in x and same in y) and use those for the bounding boxes.

Comment: I think the clustering algorithm `dbscan` might work well in your case. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html